# В или на компьютере?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно: "Я случайно увидел в/на твоём компьютере"?

Comment: Вы должны сказать, что вы увидели.

Comment: Контекст нужен. увидеть что-то можно скорее на мониторе. Вы это имеете в виду?

Answer (score 1):

Варианты:

- *Я случайно увидел **в** твоём компьютере новый блок питания.*
- *Я случайно увидел **на** твоём компьютере надпись "..."* (по-простому называя монитор компьютером или не уточняя).

*"Увидел на мониторе"* строго правильнее, но звучит заумнее в простой речи, а если сказать *"увидел на экране",* не всегда будет понятно, что речь о компьютере. *"На экране компьютера"* — больше слов и тоже заумнее.

Comment: Первая ситуация - редкая: чтобы "случайно увидеть" особенный блок питания, нужно случайно же застать чужой компьютер разобранным. Или бывают блоки питания, которые распознаются программно?

Comment: Просто на моём крышка с открытой стороны не держится (не выбросил, но стоит в стороне), вот и увидеть все внутренности легко.)))

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить только об **информационном** содержимом компьютера, то в этом случае используются оба предлога в разных глагольных сочетаниях: искать, обнаружить, посмотреть в компьютере; работать, выполнять, показывать, моделировать, набирать на компьютере.

Можно представить себе **две разные ситуации**, когда с глаголом ***видеть*** сочетаются предлоги В и НА.

*Я проходил мимо и случайно увидел на твоём компьютере (имеется в виду на открытой странице).*

*Я случайно увидел в твоем компьютере (что-то), когда искал в нем информацию для тебя.*

Предлоги, как обычно, соотносятся **со своим пространственным значением**: предлог В ― внутри пространства, а предлог НА ― на плоскости. Также предлог НА имеет обобщенное значение (работать на компьютере).

Answer (score 0):

Выбор предлога зависит от того, сам ли говорящий работал за этим компьютером в момент "увидения". Если *не* сам, то независимо от содержания увиденного, логичен предлог **на**, поскольку подразумевается: "увиденное (в какой-то момент) отображалось **на** дисплее".

Если же говорящему компьютер был временно доверен, то возможны **оба** варианта. Предлог **на** подходит к любому увиденному содержанию и может относиться как к подразумеваемому "работая **на** твоём компьютере", так и к замеченному говорящим программному обеспечению (сочетаемость: *установленному* **на** компьютере). Предлог **в** может акцентировать *внутреннее* содержание компьютера (увидел, что есть такие-то файлы **в** памяти компьютера; увидел, что **в** нём есть конкретные физические устройства - они отображаются  операционной системой).

Answer (score 0):

На компьютере может стоять чашка, а в компьютере — находиться процессор.
В других случаях выражения "*в/на твоём компьютере*" условные.

Если имеется в виду монитор, то предлог "на" необходимо сохранить:
*Я случайно увидел на твоём компьютере эту заставку.*

Если имеются в виду данные, то нужен предлог "в":
*Я случайно нашёл в твоём компьютере тот файл.*